# SQL - making use of the SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

**NEW (BUMP):
Is it possible to use the SUBSTRING function in the following SQL query, instead of JOIN?**

```
Select
c.name as "Name", e.emails as "Email"
From
CONT_EMAIL ce
JOIN CONTACTS c on c.ID = ce.name_ID
JOIN EMAILS e on e.ID = ce.email_ID
```

OLD

I already asked it on a different question, but I didn't know as much details as I do now:
So a teacher of mine asked for my help on a small database. It's a small query/job so I said yes, without knowing the fundamentals of SQL.. (I'm a good learner, but I'm used to c++/javascript).

So we've got 3 tables.
Below is how the final query should look like:

```
Cont1  |  email1
Cont1  |  email12375
Cont2  | email 7
Cont8  | email 13
Cont8  | email 500
Cont8  | email 26
Cont23 | email 95
```

We have each ID for each different name (name field is text where ID is a number)

```
CONTACTS
ID  |  name
```

The EMAILS table is similar to the CONTACTS table except that it contains e-mails

```
EMAILS
ID  |  email
```

And below is where the data relates to each other. For example,
1  |  8  |  13

1 -> is just the ID of the relation

8 -> is the ID's corresponding name of the CONTACTS table

13 -> is the ID's corresponding e-mail of the EMAILS table...

```
CONT_EMAIL 
ID  | name_ID  |  email_ID
```

I do know that this is possible, but I lack so hard of SQL basics.. Trust me, this will be the last time I say "yes" so deluded of myself

P.S -> This is on SQL Server 2008 (I even downloaded it (express edition) just to make this SQL query lol))

Comment: select contacts.name, email.email from contacts join cont_email on contacts.id = cont_email.name_id join emails on cont_email.email_id = emails.id

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Sorry, I didn't want to bump that old one. I'll keep that in mind the next time something similar happens

Comment: @Blikatat No worries. But bumping the old one is exactly what you should do. It's still the same question, and should be looked at again, because you add new information when you edit.

Comment: BUMP: I'm not sure if this will bump my original post, but here it goes.
Is it possible to do this with the "substring function"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Select
c.name as "Name", e.email as "Email"
From
CONT_EMAIL ce
JOIN CONTACTS c on c.ID = ce.name_ID
JOIN EMAILS e on e.ID = ce.email_ID
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was examining your code letter, by letter.. There's only one thing I don't understand (by the way, your code works flawlessly): Is, for example, the "c.name" a shortened version of "CONTACTS.name" and "e.email" a shortened version of "EMAILS.email"?

Comment: Yes, the "c" and "e" are aliases for the tables, and therefore can be used as "shorthand".

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't mind some comments as to why my answer was down voted twice.

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer wasn't voted "the answer"... Well, it's done now.
edit: sorry, I don't know why people downvoted your answer. If I had enough reputation, I would upvote it

Comment: Is it possible to use the substring instead of JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT @seq = @seq_1 as RelationID, cont_emails.ID, contacts.name AS ContactNAme, emails.email AS ContactEmail from cont_email 
join contacts 
ON cont_email.name_ID = contacts.ID
join emails 
ON cont_email.email_ID = emails.ID
```

This will give you the relationship ID or an auto increment value for each relation. + what the other guy's query..

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT contacts.name AS ContactName, emails.email AS ContactEmail
FROM cont_email
JOIN contacts
    ON cont_email.name_ID = contacts.ID
JOIN emails
   ON cont_email.email_ID = emails.ID
```

Comment: @rs. still gives me an error, only focusing "C.Name ContactName". Tried giving commas after each word, but it's a no go

Comment: Do you want alias? If so use AS. Like C.Name AS ContactName, E.email AS ContactEmail

Comment: @Mr.Radical your comment's not an answer.

Comment: how is this the answer? where is "1 -> is just the ID of the relation"

Comment: @Blikatat how is this the answer?